# Снятие ЭЦП на C# с xml

Tags: c#, xml, post

Подскажите пожалуйста кто сталкивался со снятием ЭЦП на C#

Отправляю POST запрос на сервер, в ответ приходит ответ с электронно цифровой подписью.

Вот что ответила мне тех.поддержка:

Ответ наших систем – бинарный контейнер эцп с текстом ответа внутри. Если открыть ответ наших систем в текстовом редакторе, то вы увидите бинарные вкрапления в начале, в конце и в середине файла ответа. Чтобы избавиться от этих вкраплений, вам надо Снять и проверить ЭЦП (в терминах программы КриптоАРМ).  Берется наш сертификат открытого ключа (Как правило это СГКО НБКИ 2018, каждый год этот сертификат меняется) и с его помощью КриптоАРМом а) проверяется, что ответ не поврежден и его автором являются именно наши сервера б) из файла удаляются эти бинарные вкрапления и у вас остаётся «чистый» xml файл ответа, пригодный для последующего анализа и обработки.

Как это можно реализовать? Что почитать?

Comment: Что значит снять?

Comment: ЭЦП это что? электро-цифро-печать? Думаю не каждый с первого раза угадает.

Comment: @nick_n_a Прошу прощения, не подумал про это) Это конечно же Электронная-цифровая-подпись.

Comment: @rdorn Сам пока не понял, что это означает. Исправил пост, и добавил туда ответ от тех.поддержки, они попытались объяснить, что мне нужно сделать.

Comment: Так понятнее. Если в общих чертах - вам нужно сохранить исходный бинарник, скормить его в КриптоАРМ, верифицировать его и снять подпись средствами КриптоАРМ, результирующий файл уже парсить. Первое что необходимо сделать - выполнить операцию в ручном режиме, потом читать мануал к КриптоАРМу по взаимодействию с внешними программами, на крайний случай можно воспользоваться запуском консольных команд КриптоАРМ из C#-кода, если таковые  имеются.

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо. Сейчас для начала попробовал отправить с помощью curl файл запроса, и получил в ответ p7s контейнер. С помощью Крипто АРМ получилось снять подпись, и получил ответ в виде XML. Теперь вопрос в том, как получить из моего WebResponse  на выходе p7s контейнер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя некоторое время, решил добить задачку. В итоге, пришлось прикупить Крипто ПРО, плюс надо было еще Крипто ПРО. NET. В итоге получаем ответ от НБКИ без электронно-цифровой подписи.

```
        //Получаем ответ от НБКИ
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        byte[] bytes = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());

        //Проверяем подпись и расшифровываем наш стрим. Далее сохраняем результат в XML        
        SignedCms cms = new SignedCms();
        cms.Decode(bytes);
        cms.CheckSignature(true);
        var content = cms.ContentInfo.Content;
        Encoding enDst = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        BinaryWriter myBinary1 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("E:\\resp.xml",FileMode.Create), enDst);
        myBinary1.Write(content);
        myBinary1.Close();
```